# Why doesn't bind(this) use correct value of "this" in jQuery hover event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Consider the following example:

```js
function toggleDropdown() {  
  console.log($(this)[0].id);  
}
$("a").hover( toggleDropdown.bind(this) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test" href="#">TEST LINK</a>
```

Similarly without jQuery similar response:

```js
function toggleDropdown() {  
  console.log(this.id);  
}
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", toggleDropdown.bind(this) );
```

```html
<a href="#!" id="myID">TEST LINK</a>
```

I don't know about plain javascript, but in jQuery isn't the value of current selector should be used in place of `this`?

Comment: `toggleDropdown.bind(this)` binds to the current value of `this`. Which would be `window` in global scope. What do you want it to be instead? If you just want the current element, then you don't need `.bind()`

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know about plain javascript, but in jQuery isn't the value of current selector should be used in place of this?

No. Absolutely not. You used `bind` which **explicitly** prevents that.

`toggleDropdown.bind(this)`:

1. Takes the value of `this` which is `window` (because it is in a browser, outside of any function, not in strict mode).
2. Creates a new function which calls `toggleDropdown` with that value as the `this` value.

So when the event listener is later called (be it by jQuery or by the standard DOM event API) it will call that new function which will call `toggleDropdown` with `window` as the `this` value.

---

If you want the `this` value to be determined by the event listener, then **don't** override it using `bind`.

```js
function toggleDropdown() {  
  console.log($(this)[0].id);  
}
$("a").hover( toggleDropdown );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test" href="#">TEST LINK</a>
```

```js
function toggleDropdown() {  
  console.log(this.id);  
}
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", toggleDropdown );
```

```html
<a href="#!" id="myID">TEST LINK</a>
```

Comment: But then why does `this` become the current element in `$("a").hover(function(){ //this is "a" })`

Comment: @user31782 — Because the event binding mechanism is designed to do that … and you aren't stopping it working using `bind`.